# How to connect 16 bits SDRAM and 32 bits processor on DE10 Standard FBGA kit

Tags: hardware, fpga, riscv, quartus

I am having a project that design a RISC V processor on DE10 kit and I've already created Verilog files for processor.
Because the processor has 32 bits data bus but the available external SDRAM has only 16 bits data, so how to connect them together?

Answer (score 0):

DE10 Standard is a Cyclone V SoC, and SDRAM is controlled by the ARM HPS, you don't need to talk to it directly. The easiest way is to talk via Avalon bus (can be up to 128bit wide). You'll need to enable a port with a U-Boot script, see an example [here](https://github.com/combinatorylogic/soc/blob/a1d282d793548030cba940496bed90ff3a29c0ba/backends/c2/hw/de10nano/Makefile)

HPS clock frequency is higher than what you can get in your logic, so a 128bit bus is still an efficient way to talk to a DDR.

Now, you'll need to connect your 32 bit data bus to a wider data bus, not a more narrow one. For reading, you should be using a cache anyway, with a line width a multiple of 128bits.

Comment: Actually, I want to build my own processor for my project instead of using HPS. So I think that I try to connect them manually by creating some module to control that SDRAM.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @ĐứcToànBùi sadly, you cannot. SDRAM is connected to a hard DDR controller in HPS. But anyway, it's a minor nuisance and it saves you a lot of LUTs, not to mention a superior performance. You don't have to use any of the HPS besides the DDR controller (see the project I linked above, it's only using DDR over Avalon and everything else is disabled).

Comment: I've seen from the datasheet that there are 1GB DDR3 SDRAM for HPS and 64MB SDRAM for FPGA. I think they are separated and normally, the 64MB SDRAM was control by a controller connected to the Nios II processor. However, in this project, I try to use my own design to replace the Nios II that means I will connect directly the SDRAM controller to my processor.

Comment: @ĐứcToànBùi sure, if 64mb one is sufficient for your needs and you're ok with performance - that should not be a problem. You'll still interface with a DDR controller over 32bit (or 128bit) Avalon or AXI anyway, you should not worry about DDR bus width unless you're also implementing your own DDR controller as well.

Comment: ohhh, Is there any way to interface with this controller directly instead of using Avalon bus. I think Avalon bus is used for SDRAM vs Nios II but I don't use that processor

Comment: @ĐứcToànBùi depends on an SDRAM controller you'll be using. Most will provide AXI, and it's far more complicated than Avalon. Some open source implementations will talk over Wishbone, which is also (my personal opinion here) is more complicated than Avalon.